# What are the steps to certify my Exe file for external users?

Tags: windows, certificate, exe, sign, signing

I have an Application/Exe file that I'd like to sign so Windows shows it as a trusted source and won't warn the end user about an "Unknown Publisher". I will be getting a certificate to use, however I do not know how I'd implemented this to Sign my Application.
My goal here is to sign my Application which can then get shipped to multiple users externally, and not show the usual "Unknown Publisher" popup. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pay the certificate mafia to get a certificate from one of the [approved vendors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/participants-list) (or look for Authenticode on the CAs website).
2. Use signtool.exe from the Windows SDK to sign your executable. Make sure to use a [time stamp server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/time-stamping-authenticode-signatures) so your signature stays valid.

Signing will make the UAC dialog less scary when the publisher can be verified.

Even after doing all of this, Windows [SmartScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-smartscreen/microsoft-defender-smartscreen-overview) might still present the user with a warning. This warning should go away after enough people use your software and signing is supposed to speed this up...

Comment: Do I need to do this within a server environment to get a time stamp? I was planning to simply certify my application on my Windows 10 PC

Comment: No, the CA will provide you with a URL that you pass to signtool as a parameter.